# Prevent flipping of the front facing camera

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm attempting to access the raw feed of android's front facing camera. By default, the front facing camera's preview is flipped horizontally so users can see themselves as if looking into a mirror - that's great, but not what I need. What's the best way to get the raw feed? Is there some way to disable the automatic flipping, or should I attempt to flip it in code myself? My application needs to display a real-time feed of the front facing camera without it being flipped like a mirror.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use a front-facing camera for barcode scanning you can use TextureView and apply a transformation matrix to it. When the texture is updated you can read the image data and use that.

See https://github.com/hadders/camera-reverse

Specifically from MainActivity.java

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
matrix.postTranslate(width, 0);
mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
```

Comment: Hey @GreenFox Fox. I just cloned the repo and ran 'gradle installDebug' from the command line and installed onto my Nexus 5. This runs. When I  launch the app and hold up some text 'ABC' it shows 'ABC' on the screen rather than the normal inverted back-to-front 'CBA' as expected. What is the exact problem?

Comment: Hey @GreenFox. What does "nothing works" mean? You should see an image. You must have a phone with a front facing camera as this thread is about front facing cameras.

Comment: the downloaded projects has no classes or whatsoever in it.

Comment: Hey @GreenFox . There is only one class; an activity. Here: https://github.com/hadders/camera-reverse/blob/master/CameraReverse/src/main/java/com/hadders/camerareverse/MainActivity.java . I suggest you read up on AndroidStudio.

Comment: doesnt matter anyway i got the problem solved, but tnx for the help though :))) @Steve

Comment: Thanks so much for the right answer! Be sure to check which camera is used and setTransform(null) when switching to the back camera.

Comment: if the device gets rotated, then the preview is flipped to be upside-down

Comment: it's only for preview

Answer (score 1):

The data from the front camera is as the camera the sees it, looking at you. The left side of its image is your right side. I think this is what you want already? When put onto a `SurfaceView` it is flipped so it acts as you say, but that's a separate cosmetic transformation.

At least, this is how every device I've seen works and I've looked hard at this to implement front camera support in [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) / [Barcode Scanner+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android).

Comment: That makes sense. I am in fact attempting to render it with a SurfaceView - how should I go about it instead?

Comment: Ah. Then I don't know. I think you'd have to receive the image data and paint it manually onto the `View`. Or maybe you have to reverse it by hand since it will just re-reverse it. I have never touched that aspect myself, just always let it fling whatever it wants onto the `SurfaceView` while I listen for the data separately.

Comment: I too would like to render it non-mirrored in the SurfaceView. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @SeanOwen did you find the solution for fipping the surface view to see a non-mirrored preview... am struggling for the solution