# Front Camera Mirror Video Android

Tags: android-camera, video-capture, front-camera

I captured the video in front camera using `MediaRecorder`. It was mirrored. For image I used `matrix.preScale()` method to reverse the image. But for video I can't reverse it.

```
if (!camera.getConfig().isFaceCamera)
{
    //For Back camera
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
}
else
{
    //For Front camera
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016675/192373) flip the video during playback. You cannot tweak MediaRecorder to flip the video. You can set an orientation hint, to indicate whether you hold the device in Portrait or Landscape orientation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249032/192373.