# How to record video in front camera using surfaceview without mirror effect?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am using SurfaceView to record the video from the front and back camera, I am able to record and save the video. But when I try to play the video front camera video is playing with the mirror effect. how to disable or remove the mirror effect while saving the video from the front camera. I used the same surface for image and the mirror effect was there for the front camera and I fixed by using the matrix (matrix.preScale()) for the bitmap. Any suggestions or referrals will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388789/how-to-keep-android-from-inverting-the-image-from-the-front-facing-camera

Comment: Did u find a solution for this issue?