# Pjsip Android Video Call: Inverted Video Preview

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

> I am using Pjsip library for SIP Video call. I am facing issue
>   displying my own view in a **SurfaceView**.

Here is the image:

[image]

Expected View:

[image: Expected view]
Fetching Preview ID in onCallMediaState

```
mVideoPreview = VideoPreview(mediaInfo.videoCapDev)
mVideoWindow = VideoWindow(mediaInfo.videoIncomingWindowId)
```

Code I have used to display this preview in my SurfaceView:

```
fun updateVideoPreview(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
    if (SipManager.currentCall != null &&
            SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoPreview != null) {
        if (videoPreviewActive) {
            val vidWH = VideoWindowHandle()
            vidWH.handle?.setWindow(holder.surface)
            val vidPrevParam = VideoPreviewOpParam()
            vidPrevParam.window = vidWH
            try {
                SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoPreview?.start(vidPrevParam)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println(e)
            }
        } else {
            try {
                SipManager.currentCall?.mVideoPreview?.stop()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the person on other side will always recieve **mirror** view of my video. But in case of my **own view**, this should not happen.
What I feel is I am displaying the preview which is sent to the other person. I am not getting a single hint about how to display my own view(without mirror effect) using Pjsip library.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you checked with the native camera app? It does the same

Comment: @RahulKhurana No. It's not like that. Here I am displaying my front view in video which results mirror effect when the person on the other side receives my view. But when you are seeing your own view in a camera, it's never mirror view.

Comment: In the image, you provided on the first arrow your thumb is on the left side and on the second arrow your thumb is on the right side. I think this is called mirror effect

Comment: @RahulKhurana Please check my updated post with the image from default camera fron view. It should look like this.

Comment: Try recording video from front camera and then play it. You will see the difference

Comment: @RahulKhurana That's totally correct. But this is the case when you are recording a video. In that case you'll never have mirror effect.

Comment: In a video call, they internally record video and upload it on the server and then plays it in continuous mode. This happens so fast that the user will feel like it is live streaming.

Comment: @RahulKhurana Okay Thank you so much. But this is not what I want. :)

Comment: Mirroring image could be better for performance level but the video isn't. You can try rotate your local preview view to 180 degrees

Comment: You could also try `android:scaleX=-1` in the XML

Comment: @RahulKhurana I have already tried that but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is replaced SurfaceView with TextureView and then check:

```
if (isFrontCamera) {
    val matrix = Matrix()
    matrix.setScale(-1.0f, 1.0f)
    matrix.postTranslate(width.toFloat(), 0.0f)
    surfacePreviewCapture.setTransform(matrix)
}
```

And it worked.
Hope it help others. :)

====== **UPDATE** ======

When I checked my back camera, the view was also flipped over there so I need to do this to make it proper:

```
surfacePreviewCapture.setTransform(null)
```

Comment: Does pjsua 2 Android sample app ..has video call feature as well.....

Comment: It does support Video call.

Comment: Default sample Pjsip video quality is very bad , can you please have a look at my post here ..how to improve video quality https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57918701/pjsip-android-video-call-inverted-video-preview

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using SurfaceView, you can use TextureView for your preview which you can flipped afterwards. Have a look at [How to keep android from inverting the image from the front facing camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388789/how-to-keep-android-from-inverting-the-image-from-the-front-facing-camera/17570037) as a reference