# How to Stop front facing camera from mirroring?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I have facing problem when i take video from front camera then video is mirroring. and I don't want to mirror effect after taking video. so please anyone have solution for stop mirroring front camera help me out.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024597/mirror-the-front-facing-camera-in-android

Comment: @FelixFroschauer this solution for only image not video

Comment: Hope this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197703/how-to-make-video-captured-by-front-camera-not-being-inverse-android