# flippin the preview horizontally : android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using a front facing camera . The preview am seeing is mirrored. if the object is in left hand side, in preview it is shown in right hand side. How can i flip the preview horizontally to fix it. Please help me with proper solution.

Comment: see here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754346/prevent-flipping-of-the-android-front-facing-camera

Comment: here they have asked to do it in textureview. am doing it in surface view... can we do it using surface view